# Execute certain commands when opening Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda

When using Anaconda in Windows you get a shortcut to the "Anaconda Prompt" which is a cmd window that with the base-environment activated and probably all the conda commands loaded.
Is there a way to have some commands executed when starting it?

I'd like to have it change to a specific directory and activate a specific environment other than `base`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Anaconda Prompt" is actually a link executing

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

The flag `/k` provided to `cmd` executes the subsequent commands, in this case `activate.bat`. To execute more commands we can just add them using the command separator `&&`, so we can use

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 && cd some_directory && conda activate some_environment
```